# Block change in start date - task

Tags: designer-workflow, tasks

I want to block users with edit permission to change the date in the field start date. Start date = today.  Is this possible? 
This is required to allow calculate correct SLA.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn`t provide inbox functionality for field level permissions.
You can choouse a few ways to get your goal:

1. Create a custom field using Visual Studio
2. Find an apropriate solution of codeplex (check this one - http://sppex.codeplex.com/)
3. Use JSLink and CSR (client side rendering) for your list (applies for SharePoint 2013 only) and redefine view or edit templates.
4. Use attribute ShowInEditForm=FALSE of your field (http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.showineditform.aspx). You can set this attributes from SharePoint PowerShell.